# Can't deserialize JSON from REST API (Wordpress) using RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, restsharp

This has been driving me nuts - I can't deserialize some JSON I'm getting back from the Wordpress public API to get my posts. I'm using RestSharp. The data I'm getting back shows a blog post, but all the properties are null. I even used Json2CSharp to model my "Post" class after what's returned.

Here's my JSON:

```js
{
   "found":1,
   "posts":[
      {
         "ID":2,
         "site_ID":89749867,
         "author":{
            "ID":2988648,
            "login":"loginname",
            "email":false,
            "name":"loginname",
            "nice_name":"loginname",
            "URL":"",
            "avatar_URL":"https:\/\/2.gravatar.com\/avatar\/e78ee2e2f7bb75a8bc5339a6bd20194e?s=96&d=identicon&r=G",
            "profile_URL":"http:\/\/en.gravatar.com\/loginname",
            "site_ID":2918427
         },
         "date":"2015-04-20T18:16:18+00:00",
         "modified":"2015-04-20T18:18:20+00:00",
         "title":"Hello world!",
         "URL":"https:\/\/myblog.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/20\/hello-world\/",
         "short_URL":"http:\/\/wp.me\/p64A2v-2",
         "content":"<p><a href=\"https:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png\"><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-3\" src=\"https:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png?w=300&#038;h=180\" alt=\"Left Shark\" width=\"300\" height=\"180\" \/><\/a><\/p>\n<p>This is your very first post. Click the Edit link to modify or delete it, or <a title=\"Direct link to Add New Post in your Dashboard\" href=\"https:\/\/wordpress.com\/post\">start a new post<\/a>. If you like, use this post to tell readers why you started this blog and what you plan to do with it.<\/p>\n<p>Happy blogging!<\/p>\n",
         "excerpt":"<p>This is your very first post. Click the Edit link to modify or delete it, or start a new post. If you like, use this post to tell readers why you started this blog and what you plan to do with it. Happy blogging!<\/p>\n",
         "slug":"hello-world",
         "guid":"http:\/\/myblog.wordpress.com\/?p=1",
         "status":"publish",
         "sticky":false,
         "password":"",
         "parent":false,
         "type":"post",
         "discussion":{
            "comments_open":true,
            "comment_status":"open",
            "pings_open":true,
            "ping_status":"open",
            "comment_count":0
         },
         "likes_enabled":true,
         "sharing_enabled":true,
         "like_count":0,
         "i_like":0,
         "is_reblogged":0,
         "is_following":0,
         "global_ID":"7a5ad608c4e80f7c2463eead8d34f435",
         "featured_image":"https:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png",
         "post_thumbnail":{
            "ID":3,
            "URL":"https:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png",
            "guid":"http:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png",
            "mime_type":"image\/png",
            "width":620,
            "height":372
         },
         "format":"standard",
         "geo":false,
         "menu_order":0,
         "page_template":"",
         "publicize_URLs":[

         ],
         "tags":{

         },
         "categories":{
            "Uncategorized":{
               "ID":1,
               "name":"Uncategorized",
               "slug":"uncategorized",
               "description":"",
               "post_count":1,
               "parent":0,
               "meta":{
                  "links":{
                     "self":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/categories\/slug:uncategorized",
                     "help":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/categories\/slug:uncategorized\/help",
                     "site":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "attachments":{
            "3":{
               "ID":3,
               "URL":"https:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png",
               "guid":"http:\/\/myblog.files.wordpress.com\/2015\/04\/left_shark_5x3.png",
               "date":"2015-04-20T18:17:33+00:00",
               "post_ID":2,
               "file":"left_shark_5x3.png",
               "mime_type":"image\/png",
               "extension":"png",
               "title":"Left Shark",
               "caption":"",
               "description":"",
               "alt":"Left Shark",
               "thumbnails":{

               },
               "height":372,
               "width":620,
               "exif":{
                  "aperture":0,
                  "credit":"",
                  "camera":"",
                  "caption":"",
                  "created_timestamp":0,
                  "copyright":"",
                  "focal_length":0,
                  "iso":0,
                  "shutter_speed":0,
                  "title":"",
                  "orientation":0
               },
               "meta":{
                  "links":{
                     "self":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/media\/3",
                     "help":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/media\/3\/help",
                     "site":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867",
                     "parent":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/posts\/2"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "attachment_count":1,
         "metadata":[
            {
               "id":"9",
               "key":"_thumbnail_id",
               "value":"3"
            }
         ],
         "meta":{
            "links":{
               "self":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/posts\/2",
               "help":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/posts\/2\/help",
               "site":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867",
               "replies":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/posts\/2\/replies\/",
               "likes":"https:\/\/public-api.wordpress.com\/rest\/v1.1\/sites\/89749867\/posts\/2\/likes\/"
            }
         },
         "capabilities":{
            "publish_post":false,
            "delete_post":false,
            "edit_post":false
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here's my class (with some properties commented out so I didn't have to build those out:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace thenickwilson_SPA_NEW.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int site_ID { get; set; }
        //public Author author { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string short_URL { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public string excerpt { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public bool sticky { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool parent { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        //public Discussion discussion { get; set; }
        public bool likes_enabled { get; set; }
        public bool sharing_enabled { get; set; }
        public int like_count { get; set; }
        public int i_like { get; set; }
        public int is_reblogged { get; set; }
        public int is_following { get; set; }
        public string global_ID { get; set; }
        public string featured_image { get; set; }
        //public PostThumbnail post_thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public bool geo { get; set; }
        public int menu_order { get; set; }
        public string page_template { get; set; }
        public List<object> publicize_URLs { get; set; }
        //public Tags tags { get; set; }
        //public Categories categories { get; set; }
        //public Attachments attachments { get; set; }
        public int attachment_count { get; set; }
        //public List<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
        //public Meta3 meta { get; set; }
        //public Capabilities capabilities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the rest of my code:

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(Post))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/");
            var request = new RestRequest("sites/{id}/posts", Method.GET);
            request.AddUrlSegment("id", "myblog.wordpress.com");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            var response = client.Execute<List<Post>>(request);

            return this.Ok(response);
        }
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that the API returns a "found" element as well as "posts", but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving an array or list of Posts wrapped in a container object, so try with this:

```
  public class MyContainer
  { 
       public List<Post> posts {get;set;}
  }
```

And:

```
  var response = client.Execute<MyContainer>(request);
```

You can view your json deserialized here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: That was exactly the issue. Thank you. Is this common with REST API's?

Comment: I don't think, depends on what the server returns. I have restful service returning a list of objects without wrapping it.Fortunately exist tools like that json viewer.Well the json is clear, the container also has a "found" field.